# How to convert pdf to HTML using python pdfminer?

Tags: python, html, pdf, pdfminer, pdf-to-html

Is there any code snippet that will work? I have tried this for converting pdf to html

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
import os
import contextlib 
import tempfile
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
converter = HTMLConverter if format == 'html' else TextConverter
out_file = "A:\folder"
in_file = "A:\folder\pyhtml.html"
pdf_filename = 'insurance.pdf'
device = converter(rsrcmgr, out_file, codec='utf-8', laparams=laparams)
PDFPage.get_pages(rsrcmgr, device, in_file, pagenos=[1], maxpages=1)

with contextlib.closing(tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='r', suffix='.xml')) as xmlin:
    cmd = 'pdftohtml -xml -nodrm -zoom 1.5 -enc UTF-8 -noframes "%s" "%s"' % (
            pdf_filename, xmlin.name.rpartition('.')[0])
    os.system(cmd + " >/dev/null 2>&1")
    result = xmlin.read().decode('utf-8')
```

when i run the above code it gives me following erroe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a:\folder\new - Copy.py", line 14, in <module>
    device = converter(rsrcmgr, out_file, codec='utf-8', laparams=laparams)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

If there is attempt of `.write` that means you should provide write-able file-handle rather than `str`, you might use `with open`... which will take care of closing file for you as follow, replace

```
in_file = "A:\folder\pyhtml.html"
device = converter(rsrcmgr, out_file, codec='utf-8', laparams=laparams)
```

using

```
in_file = "A:\folder\pyhtml.html"
with open(in_file, "w") as out_file:
    device = converter(rsrcmgr, out_file, codec='utf-8', laparams=laparams)
```

If you want to know more about `open` read [Built-in Functions docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)